# What am I doing wrong with this Service Stack Web Service or jQuery call?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, servicestack

I was able to get Service Stack's Hello World example working, but now I'm trying to expand it a little to return a custom **Site** object.  I made a simple test html file that uses jQuery to pull a result back, but I'm not getting the **Site** object returned (I think).

Here's my Web Service:

```
using Funq;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
using System;

namespace My.WebService
{

    public class SiteRepository
    {

    }

    public class Site
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Uri { get; set; } //switch to the real uri class if you find it useful
    }

    public class SiteService : Service //: RestServiceBase<Site>
    {
        public SiteRepository Repository { get; set; } //Injected by IOC

        public object Get(Site request)
        {
            //return new Site { Name = "Google", Uri = "http://www.google.com" };
            return new SiteResponse {Result = new Site {Name = "Google", Uri = "http://www.google.com"}};
        }
    }

    public class SiteResponse
    {
        public Site Result { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiteAppHost : AppHostBase
    {

        public SiteAppHost()
            : base("Site Web Services", typeof(SiteService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            container.Register(new SiteRepository());

            Routes
                .Add<Site>("/site")
                .Add<Site>("/site/{Id}/");
        }
    }

    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {


        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new SiteAppHost().Init();
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the test HTML file using jQuery.  I added the ?callback=? because I'm running both the Web Service and the making the call from the same machine.

```
 <html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
    // we will add our javascript code here 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // do stuff when DOM is ready
        alert("Hello world!");
        //the ?callback=? part is for testing on the same server as the web service
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:61549/site?callback=?", function(sitesReturned) {
            alert(sitesReturned);   // alert box contains:   [object Object]
            alert(sitesReturned.Name);  //alert box contains:  undefined
            alert(sitesReturned.length == 1) //alert box contains:  false
            var parsed = JSON.parse(sitesReturned); //this fails silently
            alert(parsed.Name); // the alert box does not load
        });

        alert("Goodbye world!");
    });                                    
 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
   <!-- we will add our HTML content here -->                                        
   Hello
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes...

- **but I'm not getting the Site object returned (I think)**

$.getJSON will have a response that looks like this

`{"result":{"name":"Google","uri":"http://www.google.com"}}` so the name/uri properties are inside the `result` property.

```
alert(sitesReturned.result);   // will still contain [object Object]
alert(sitesReturned.result.name);  //should contain Google
alert(sitesReturned.result.uri.length == 1) //contains false since 21 != 1
```

- **I'm running both the Web Service and the making the call from the same machine.**

Not exactly sure what you mean by this. If your HTML file that contains the jQuery code is being served by `http://localhost:61549` you don't need to use JSONP.

- **var parsed = JSON.parse(sitesReturned); //this fails silently**

The sitesReturned parameter is already parsed into a JavaScript object so this line fails since it is trying to parse an object and not a String. See documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Also, I didn't see a reference or `<script>` tag but I'm assuming your using Douglas Crockford's JSON library for `JSON.parse()`.

**From documentation:**

"The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of the response."

Comment: your explanation helped a lot on the jquery side, but it wasn't the only problem-the service stack part had issues too.  I will mark yours as the answer but my answer was necessary too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Stupid mistake.

```
public class SiteService : Service //: RestServiceBase<Site>
    {
        public SiteRepository Repository { get; set; } //Injected by IOC

        public object Get(Site request)
        {
            //return new Site { Name = "Google", Uri = "http://www.google.com" };
            return new SiteResponse {Result = new Site {Name = "Google", Uri = "http://www.google.com"}};
        }
    }
```

should have been

```
public class SiteService : IService //: RestServiceBase<Site>
    {
        public SiteRepository Repository { get; set; } //Injected by IOC

        public object Get(Site request)
        {
            //return new Site { Name = "Google", Uri = "http://www.google.com" };
            return new SiteResponse {Result = new Site {Name = "Google", Uri = "http://www.google.com"}};
        }
    }
```

and I needed to add the following namespace:  `using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;`